# React/Express App when deployed to Heroku only responds with index.html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm attempting to deploy my first react + express app. It works locally and runs both the front end and backed on port 8080. However when I deploy to heroku, the backend only responds with index.html. I've tried changing the scripts in package.json and the paths in server.js but I'm pretty stuck in terms of getting more information out of this error and what to try next. When I first deployed to heroku I received an H10 error, but then following an article recommendation I installed serve. That package resolved the H10 error, but the app doesn't respond with the json from the database. What am I missing here?

https://runtopia.herokuapp.com/

Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "runtopia",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.9.26",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "serve": "^11.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
    },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

server.js

```
    const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const Datastore = require('nedb');

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
app.use(express.json());

// ADDED TO WORK FOR HEROKU
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'build')));


//retrieve data from database
app.get('/chartData', (request,response) => {
    db.find({},(err,data) => {
    if (err){
        response.end();
        return
    }
    response.json(data)
    }) 
})     



const db = new Datastore({filename:'./database.db', autoload: true});


app.post('/fitData', (request, response) => {
    const fitData = request.body
    fitData.map(week => 
        {
        console.log("logging week",week.weekYear)
            db.update({'weekYear' : week.weekYear}, week, {upsert: true, multi: true}, function (){});
    })
    response.json({status: "this is the backend saying, got the lastest fitbit Data!"})
})

 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart2 from './Chart';
import './App.css';
import moment from 'moment';
import _ from 'lodash';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fitData:[],
      chartData: [],
    }
    this.grab = this.grab.bind(this);
    this.queryDb = this.queryDb.bind(this)
    
  }
  //populates chart with data currently in db
  componentDidMount(){
    this.queryDb()
  }

  async post(){
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.fitData)
    }
    const response = await fetch('/fitData', options);
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    await this.queryDb()
  }

  async queryDb(){
    const response = await fetch('/chartData');
    const dbData = await response.json()
    let sorted = dbData.sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1)
    this.setState({chartData:sorted})
  }
  
render(){
    return (
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="Top"></div>
        <div className="Title">
          <p className="runtopia">RUNTOPIA.</p> 
          <div>
            <button className="big-button" onClick= {this.grab}>Get Data</button>
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div className="Weekly">
          <Chart2 key={this.state.chartData} data={this.state.chartData} />
        </div>
        <div className="Bottom"></div>
      </div>

    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you building your react app before you push it to heroku?

Comment: Hello, yes I use npm run build and then commit all files to github which then triggers a new build in heroku